# ITK and visual studio 2010 "Hello World!"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, itk

I'm trying to use ITK with visual studio 2010. Are there "Hello World!" like examples that you can direct me to that can get someone up and running using those both tools together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Getting up and running requires getting the appropriate version of CMake, and configuring it appropriately. After running CMake, you'll have a full build system with a .sln that should "just work" in VS 2010.

The best option I know of for documentation of the process is the [ITK Software Guide](http://www.itk.org/ItkSoftwareGuide.pdf).  While it's examples are for VS 2003, the process is the same for VS 2010.